# How to return statement in java method?

Tags: java

my situation here is i cant return my statement for my method because my method cant identify my return statement.

```
public static String j(){

 try{
    String k ="10";
    System.out.println(k);
    }

 catch (Exception ignore) {}

 return k; // error: cannot find symbol

}
```

error output :

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable k
location: class DatabaseSQL
```

But if i put my return statement at try{} it will return "missing return statement"

```
public static String j(){ //missing return statement

 try{
    String k ="10";
    System.out.println(k);

    return k; 
    }

 catch (Exception ignore) {}

}
```

**ANSWER**

```
 public static String j(){
 String k ="10";// put String k before and outside try{}

 try{

    System.out.println(k);

    return k; 
    }

 catch (Exception ignore) {}

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is about variable scoping. A variable declared inside a block is only visible inside that block. Try:

```
public static String j(){
  String k = null;
  try{
     k ="10";
     System.out.println(k);
  }

  catch (Exception ignore) {}

  return k;

}
```

Note that you should never just silently eat exceptions. I know this is just a bit of test code but get out of that habit as soon as possible and you will save yourself a lot of pain in the long run!

Comment: +1 for you for the nice tips, anyway everyone seem to give a similar answer so credit to everyone. +1 to all answer.

Answer (score 5):

Declare your `String k` outside `try` block

```
public static String j(){
    String k="";
    try{
        k ="10";
        System.out.println(k);
    }
     catch (Exception ignore) {}
    return k; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because you define `String k` in `try` block so it will be `local variable` cannot be access outside this block

and in the second code you wrote `return` statement  in `try` block and there is no another one on `catch` so you got this error : `"missing return statement"`

so the true code need to be like this :

```
public static String j(){ 
   String k ="10";
   try{
     System.out.println(k);
     }
   catch (Exception ignore) {}

return k; 
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Define like below, In First case, your local variable `k` type of `String` has a scope withing the try block

```
public static String j(){
 String k ="10";
 try{
    System.out.println(k);
    }

 catch (Exception ignore) {}

 return k;    
}
```

In second case, You haven't return anything, if an Exception caught. You either rethrow the Exception, or return something meaninfully.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is because k is not defined outside try and catch. Thats why its only working if you return in the try block if you also return null at the bottom that will be the return value of it cant return in the try block.

Do this instead and it'll work:

```
 public static String j(){
  String k = "";

  try{
     k ="10";
     System.out.println(k);
     }

  catch (Exception ignore) {}

  return k;
```

}

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare the String variable in the method scope like:

```
public static String j(){
   String k = "";
   try{
       k ="10";
       System.out.println(k);
    } catch (Exception ignore) {}

    return k;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
try{
    String k ="10"; // k declare inside the try and it will visible inside try
    System.out.println(k);
    }

 catch (Exception ignore) {}

 return k; // error: cannot find symbol // k not visible out side the try

}
```

You can try this way

```
String k ="";
try{  
 k="10";
 System.out.println(k);
} catch (Exception ignore) {}

 return k; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because `k` is not defined in the scope of the `return` line. You can change it like this:

```
public static String j(){ //
    String k = "10";
    try {
      System.out.println(k);
    } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    return k; 
}
```

If your string assignment should be within the `try` block, give it some default value during declaration (I would recommend `null`) and then reassign it in the `try` block.

Answer (score 3):

On your fist try, `k` in the return statement is out of the scope where it is defined (inside the `try` block).

On your second try, *not all code paths in your method returns a value*. Your best bet is define `k` outside the try statement and return it at the end.

```
public static String j(){
    String k ="10";

     try {
        System.out.println(k);
    }    
    catch (Exception ignore) {}
    return k;     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to your code the method returns a value of type `String`.

```
public static String j(){
```

You have to ensure that the return value is known for each possible execution path. If everything is ok (try-block completed w/o error), `k` is returned. But in case of a failure (catch-block is executed) the return value for the method is undefined, because there is no specification of the value in or after the catch-block.